# Why is the top part of the stem on my umbrella tree turning soft and different colors? And the leaves have brown ish spots on the new leaves

Tags: identification, houseplants, diseases

Help! I got this umbrella plant just a little while ago and it did have aphids (I did get rid of them). After them, the plants condition has gotten worse! The upper part of the stem is extremely soft to the point where it can bend easily and certain parts of the soft part of the stem is a different color. Also, in the one of the pictures, you can see that the stem thats soft is getting more thinner than the rest. The leaves on the top part (the new ish ones) have brown spots on them and on the edges. I've tried soap and water a couple of times, 1 part milk and 1 part water one time, and safers 3in1 garden spray one time aswell.  Still, nothing has changed, and I think its getting even more worse! Should I have used the the 3in1 garden spray for fungicide/insectide/miticide more than once? Please help  and thank you so much if your do[image]
[image]

enter image description here

[image]

[image]

Comment: The white stuff you see in the picture is just from me wiping with a paper towel!